# <audio> don't update audio.currentTime

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, web, frontend

In my studies in reactJs, i try make a audio player with my controls config, but a can't update my currentTime in bar

```
useEffect(() => {
    const audio = document.getElementById("audio");

    if (audio){
      // state setters wrappers
      const setAudioData = () => {
        setDuration(audio.duration);
        setCurTime(audio.currentTime);
      }

      const setAudioTime = () => setCurTime(audio.currentTime);

      // DOM listeners: update React state on DOM events
      audio.addEventListener("loadeddata", setAudioData);

      audio.addEventListener("timeupdate", setAudioTime);

      // React state listeners: update DOM on React state changes
      playing ? audio.play() : audio.pause();

      if (clickedTime && clickedTime !== curTime) {
        console.log(audio.currentTime, clickedTime, '1')
        audio.currentTime = 5; // i try use 5 to test, but the correct is clickedTime
        console.log(audio.currentTime, clickedTime, '2')
        setClickedTime(null);
      } 

      // effect cleanup
      return () => {
        audio.removeEventListener("loadeddata", setAudioData);
        audio.removeEventListener("timeupdate", setAudioTime);
      }
    }
  });

const togglePlay = () => {
    setPlaying(true)
  };

  const togglePause = () => {
    setPlaying(false)
  };

  const handleProgress = (progress) => {
    setClickedTime(progress);
  };

<div className="player">
  <audio id="audio">
    <source src={audioRecord[currentAudioIndex].url} type="audio/mpeg"/>
    Your browser does not support the <code>audio</code> element.
  </audio>
  <div className="controls" style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "row", flexWrap: "nowrap", justifyContent: "space-between", alignItems: "center" }}>
    <div style={{ marginRight: 15 }}>
      {playing ?
        <Pause handleClick={togglePause} /> :
        <Play handleClick={togglePlay} />
      }
    </div>
    <div style={{ width: "100%" }}>
      <Bar curTime={curTime} duration={duration} onTimeUpdate={(playedSeconds) => handleProgress(playedSeconds)} />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

last consoles

0 5.960204 '1'

0 5.960204 '2'

0 11.855388 '1'

0 11.855388 '2'

i play, pause, get current, get duration, just can't update, what i did wrong ?

Comment: Could you create minimal reproducible example? I made [this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-bessie-x5vghh) and your logic seems to work just fine.